# Faux Databinding a Recordset to a Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview, ado, recordset

I am updating a very old vb6 program that includes recordsets bound to an old third party grid control. The recordset functionality is so ingrained into the program that it is not an option to replace them. So, I replaced the unfunctional grid with a datagridview and I fill it using a dataadapter and a dataset. The problem is that the recordset was originally bound to the grid and using a dgv breaks the binding.

So this is what I am trying to do. I have a function that passes in the old recordset and the new dgv, and fills it. I would like to create a dynamic handler to the dgv's selectionchanged event to update the rs with the current position on the dgv (rs.aboluteposition = dgv.row), thus updating the rs cursor to the current position in the dgv, making a sort of faux data binding.

Something like this....

```
AddHandler dgv.SelectionChanged, AddressOf RefreshRecordset

Public Sub RefreshRecordset()

   myRS.AbsolutePosition = dgv.Row

End Sub
```

A couple things though. I have to track if the event handler was already created, and the associated recordset that goes with this specific datagridview. Also, since this is a global function to update many dgvs with many rs, it needs to have a way to track the recordset. I was thinking of somehow using the tag of dgv? Maybe create a dictionary of all the recordsets then look it up by the name of the dgv?

Comment: There is. It worked but I cannot post the answer for another 8 hours since I am a noob. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Below is my original method that worked pretty well. I eventually refined it and put it in a class for each recordset. I also updated it to accept true dbgrids. By wrapping it in a class, I was able to remove the dictionaries. In the New function, I pass in either grid and a recordset. From there, I set up event handlers to handle both the grid row change and also the recordset MoveComplete event. I had to use the MoveComplete because the RecordsetChangeComplete has a bug and doesn't always fire correctly. I just check in the MoveComplete if the record count had changed. If so, refresh the grid. Lastly, I added a removehandler for each of the events in the finalize function.

////// The Original Answer //////

For instance, like this... (I CAN'T believe this worked...)

```
    Public dict as new Dictionary(Of String, ADODB.Recordset)

    Public Sub FillGrid(ByRef dgv as DataGridView, ByRef rs as ADODB.RecordSet)
    '.... Fill the grid with the tableadapter, blah blah.

       If Not dict.ContainsValue(rs) Then
         dict.add(dgv.Name, rs)
         AddHandler dgv.SelectionChanged, AddressOf RefreshRecordset)
         ' To make the event fire correctly, I think
         dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect 
       End if

    End Sub

    Public Sub RefreshRecordset(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
       Dim dgv as DataGridView = Ctype(sender, DataGridView)
       If dict.ContainsKey(dgv.Name) then
          Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset = dict(dgv.Name)
          rs.AbsolutePosition = dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex
       End if
    End Sub
```

Now I need to create a handler to the recordset to refresh the dgv everytime the recordset is updated.

And btw, I know there are probably other ways to do this and I would absolutely would love to hear them! Please feel free!

Thanks!